# django multiple inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm currently working on a django project where i need to do multiple legacy. The project in it self has an admin with multiple websites. In my admin part i've created a Member class containing all mandatory info for a member. Then all individual sites have an MemberExtra class created from the Member class from the admin where i add all complementary information. When i launch my server (python manage.py runserver...) i've that error :

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
programsite.memberextra: Accessor for field 'member_ptr' clashes with related field 'Member.memberextra'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'member_ptr'.
programsite.memberextra: Reverse query name for field 'member_ptr' clashes with related field 'Member.memberextra'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'member_ptr'.
gourmandiz.memberextra: Accessor for field 'member_ptr' clashes with related field 'Member.memberextra'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'member_ptr'.
gourmandiz.memberextra: Reverse query name for field 'member_ptr' clashes with related field 'Member.memberextra'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'member_ptr'.
```

admin/models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    prog = models.ForeignKey(Program, verbose_name=_("Program"))
    status = models.CharField(_("Status"), m    status = models.CharField(_("Status"), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICE\
S)
    points_avai = models.BigIntegerField(_("
Current Points"), null=True)
    points_notavai = models.BigIntegerField(_("Future Points"), null=True)
    cn = models.CharField(_("Company name"), max_length=250)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("Full name"), max_length=250)
    b_add = models.CharField(_("Billing address"), max_length=250)
    b_city = models.CharField(_("Billing City"), max_length=250)
    b_zip = models.CharField(_("Billing ZIP code"), max_length=250)
    b_country = models.CharField(_("Billing country"), max_length=250)
    prog_start_date = models.DateField(_("Program start date"), null=True)
    prog_end_date = models.DateField(_("Program end date"), null=True)
    member_id = models.CharField(_("Member ID"), max_length=250, primary_key=T\
rue)
    client_id = models.CharField(_("Client ID"), max_length=250, help_text="Nu\
méro de client.")
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.full_name + " (" + str(self.member_id) + ")"

    class Meta:                                                     
        verbose_name = _("Member")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Members")
```

programsite/models.py:

```
class MemberExtra(Member):
 email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), max_length=100, null=True)
 tel = models.CharField(_("Tel"), max_length=100, null=True)
 patrick = models.CharField(_("Patrick"), max_length=100, null=True)
 test42 = models.CharField(_("Test42"), max_length=100, null=True)
```

gourmandiz/models.py:

```
class MemberExtra(Member):
     email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), max_length=100, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you inherit your model twice, and both the child models have the same name. This results in having twice the same related_name, which is a problem for Django.

Your solution to add

```
member = models.OneToOneField(Member, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")"
```

in your `MemberExtra` model works, but you loose the implicit inheritance magic that Django do to let you access both your models in one:

With your solution you have to do:

```
from programsite.models import MemberExtra
m = MemberExtra.objects.get(member__full_name = "Foobar")
m.email # -> returns the email of your MemberExtra instance
m.member.b_add # -> returns the address of the inherited member instance
```

Where, with the Django native inheritance, you can do:

```
from programsite.models import MemberExtra
m = MemberExtra.objects.get(full_name = "Foobar")
m.email # -> returns the email of your MemberExtra instance
m.b_add # -> returns the address of the inherited member instance
```

Which is much cleaner in my opinion.

To manage the inheritance, Django actually creates a `OneToOneField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).
This field is called `<parentclass>_ptr`, `member_ptr` in you case.

<strike>If you manually create a `OneToOneField` named `<parentclass>_ptr`, and give it a related_name, Django is still able to find the parent model, and will not complain about identical related_names.</strike>

In your case, just add

```
member_ptr = models.OneToOneField(Member, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")"
```

in both your `MemberExtra` model definitions.

This solution works, but is not how it should be done. Django provides a flag `parent_link` that, when set to true, will tell Django that this is the field that will be used to access the parent class.

So you can add a field

```
member = models.OneToOneField(Member, parent_link=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")"
```

which will still work if, for some reason, Django needs to rename the default pointer to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The `related_name` for a FK has to be unique. When you have an FK with a default `related_name` (unspecified), that is inherited by multiple other models, all of the models end up with the same `related_name`. See the section in the Django docs entitled [Be careful with `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name).

The solution is to set the `related_name` argument of the FK to something like:

```
prog = models.ForeignKey(Program, verbose_name=_("Program"), related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

Django will then sub the app label and module name into to the string, making the `related_name` unique for each of the subclasses.

Comment: I solved my problem, i add "member = models.OneToOneField(Member, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")" in my "MemberExtra".